# How do I run multiple scripts with a single command using the terminal? (python - otoole)

Tags: python

For instance, I want to run these all at once:

> > otoole convert csv datafile data datafile.txt
> > python preprocess_data.py otoole datafile.txt preprocessed_datafile.txt

So I need to write a script that I can call in the terminal and will run those two commands automatically.

I don't have much experience using the terminal and I'm just beginning to read about executing shell commands with python; os.system, subprocess.run, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you're running in a bash terminal, and if so, you can chain multiple commands by using `&&`:

```
python some_file.py && python another_file.py && otoole blabla
```

Alternatively, create a single file `some_filename.sh` and in it,

```
#!/bin/bash

python some_file.py && python another_file.py && otoole blabla
```

Then you can call the script in the terminal:

```
./some_filename.sh
```

For bash scripts, take a look at [this](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-script.php).

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for is to write one script that I can call. For instance in the terminal I would call:

 >python3 some script.py, where that script performs: >otoole convert csv datafile data datafile.txt 
>python preprocess_data.py otoole datafile.txt preprocessed_datafile.txt, 

instead of just combing them using && in the terminal. Sorry if I wasn't clear.

Is there a library that can convert from/to datafile and datapackage?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, the bash script above should meet your requirement. All you need to do is to call that `.sh` script, which itself contains the commands you require. I don't know what is the datafile and datapackage you're referring to.

Comment: End goal: run each command in the terminal using one script

Start in CLEWS_CANADA folder
The script will then run this command in the folder: 
“python3 Build_Canada.py Canada.yaml”

Then the script will go into otoole_folder (eg “cd otoole_folder”)

Then run the following commands, in order: 

“>otoole convert csv datafile data datafile.txt 
>python preprocess_data.py otoole datafile.txt preprocessed_datafile.txt 

The script will need to wait for each command to finish before moving on to the next command